# Create Ember View from a jQuery object

Tags: ember.js

I'm looking into integrating Ember with an existing Rails application, to take advantage of Ember's bindings, events (didInsertElement, etc.) ...

Now I don't want to transfer my erb views to handlebars, but instead I want to create Ember View objects and attach them to various elements already in the DOM. For example, I might have

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="header">

    </div>

    <div class="content">

    </div>

    <div class="footer">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and (on DOM ready) create a View for each element:

```
App.HeaderView = Ember.View.create({
   // capture $('.header') to this
   // console.log(this.$().attr('class')) should then output `header`
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok the following works but I haven't fully tested it.

Inspired by @pangratz's [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/574) I extend `Ember.View` with the following method for

```
Ember.View = Ember.Object.extend(
  /** @scope Ember.View.prototype */ {
  // ........

  wrap: function(target) {
    this._insertElementLater(function() { 
       // Set all attributes name/values from target
       var target_attrs = {};
       var $this = this.$();

       for (var attr, i=0, attrs=$(target)[0].attributes, l=attrs.length; i<l; i++){
          attr = attrs.item(i)
          var attrName = attr.nodeName;
          var attrValue = attr.nodeValue;

          if(attrName === 'id') continue;
          $this.attr(attrName, attrValue);
       }

       // Set HTML from target
       $this.html($(target).html()); 
       Ember.$(target).replaceWith($this); 

    });   
    return this;

  },        

  // ........

});
```

Basically it copies the html content of the target element as well as its attributes. Then by just doing

```
App.HeaderView = Ember.View.create().wrap('.header');
```

the `.header` element (that is already in the DOM) is now in App.HeaderView.

See http://jsfiddle.net/KFcgA/4/

Answer (score 5):

use `appendTo()` on a view: `App.HeaderView.appendTo('.header')` see http://jsfiddle.net/yFke9/

**UPDATE**

I think this is currently not possible. Please proof me wrong! You could create a workaround for this, although this is a hack, see http://jsfiddle.net/jFTk5/. The workaround basically adds the view via `append()` and inside the `didInsertElement` callback it replaces the specific element via jQuery's `replaceWith`.

```
App.HeaderView = Ember.View.create({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('hello from HeaderView'),
    classNames: ['header'],
    didInsertElement: function() {
        Ember.$('.header').replaceWith(this.$());
    }
}).append();
```

If you're going with this solution you could write a Mixin which handles this for you, see http://jsfiddle.net/KFcgA/.

```
App.ReplaceWith = Ember.Mixin.create({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        var el = this.get('elementToReplace');
        Ember.$(el).replaceWith(this.$());
    }
});

App.HeaderView = Ember.View.create(App.ReplaceWith, {
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Hello from HeaderView'),
    classNames: ['header'],
    elementToReplace: '.header'    
}).append();
```

Comment: This is not capturing the `.header` element into App.HeaderView. It just adds it **into** the `.header` element.

Comment: I assumed you want to do that because you wrote `attach this to $('.header')`

Comment: I created a Pull Request for this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/574

Comment: I think its still not working as expected, since it removes previous content. A possible way to do this is to get the App.HeaderView id attribute, with App.HeaderView.$().attr('id'). Then, set the id of .header, and finally App.HeaderView.$().remove(). Still working on it...

Comment: Ok, so you want to wrap an existing DOM element inside an Ember.View? Can you give a more detailed example? Whats inside the .header div?