# Ember JS/Handlebars view helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Currently, if we define our view as `{{#view App.myView}}`, ember/handlebars will wrap the view element inside a `<div id="ember-1234" class='ember-view'>`.

Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want to set tagName as ''.

```
App.MyView = Em.View.extend({
    tagName: ''
});
```

At least it stops wrapping inner contents.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to customize view element's id, you can use:

```
{{#view App.myView id="my-id"}}
```

Comment: But it's still wrapped inside a div when it's generated. I want to get rid of the wrapping div.

Comment: So what you want is not a view... Could you please elaborate a little your code sample? What is your aim? Maybe you could just include your content without a view.

Answer (score 2):

I usually think my views as wrapper. For example, if the initial given html code is :

```
<div class="item"><p>my stuff></p></div>
```

Then I create a view with a tagName property as "div" (which is default), and classNames property as "item". This will render, with proper handlebars template :

```
{#view App.myView}
    <p>my stuff></p>
{/view}

-> render as

<div id="ember-1234" class="ember-view item">
    <p>my stuff></p>
</div>
```

Then if you need to have your proper ID on this div, you could define the "elementId" property on your view class (before create()). (@see [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L737))

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the 'ember-view' class which is not customizable *(element type being customizable thanks to the `tagName` attribute...)*.

Actually, Ember later uses this class to register (once!) an event listener on the document in order to dispatch events to the JS view.

I don't mind it would be that simpler to avoid using this class. There would have to find another way to select all ember's controlled element, but I have no idea how.

See [source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/system/event_dispatcher.js), @ line 117.

Comment: Actually, I was saying that myView will be generated like this <div id="ember-1234" class="ember-view"><div id="myView"></div></div>. Basically, I don't want #myView to be wrapped inside #ember-1234

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to achieve something like jQuery's `replaceWith`? You can use this in Ember.js when my Pull Request gets merged: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/574.

Also have a look at [Create Ember View from a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617789/create-ember-view-from-a-jquery-object)