# How do I create this html structure via my App.ApplicationView/application template?

Tags: ember.js

I ultimately want my application's html structure to look like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

My application's root element is the default `body` element. But my "application view" is everything within the body tag (listed above). The footer may have elements tied to the `ApplicationController`, so it needs to be included in the application template.

I would think to do this like so:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <div id="wrapper"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </script>
</body>
```

But that creates the following structure, which is not desirable:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="wrapper"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So then I could change the `ApplicationView` to the following, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732398/ember-js-handlebars-view-helper).

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: ""
});
```

Ember now throws an exception: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null` on line 18779 of [the current version of ember](http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.js)

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.2.1+pre.ce3a6b7c
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.4+canary.7af6fcb0
DEBUG: Handlebars
DEBUG: jQuery
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

So I'm not sure how to create the proposed html structure using the application root. Any hints or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `outlets` for this. Although, it depends on your application.

The `application` template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{outlet wrapper}}
  {{outlet footer}}
</script>
```

And the `ApplicationRoute` code:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('wrapper', {
      outlet: 'wrapper'
      controller: 'application'
    });
    this.render('footer', {
      outlet: 'footer',
      controller: 'application'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: That's still producing a div around the wrapper and footer elements for me: http://jsfiddle.net/YdvpU/1/