# attach view to exists element with embjer.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

what's the implementation of attaching exist html element to Ember.js view without using any template engine. ?
for example in Backbone.js i should give the view the el property

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9622361/359104

Answer (score 0):

In view you can do:

```
didInsertElement: function () {
    var domNode = this.$().get(0);

    $(domNode).append('//your html element goes');
}
```